# Could not connect the action : to target of class NSApplication

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I come from a Cocoa touch background and there's one point I'm stuck on, I'm trying to create a ViewController from scratch and connect objects in my xib to actions in my new ViewController. I changed the file's owner to my ViewController and added outlets, and the compiler seems to be happy with what I've done.

[image]

[image]

But when I run my application, the connections seem to fail with: 'Could not connect the action start: to target of class NSApplication,' but where is this NSApplication reference hiding? To the best of my knowledge my ViewController has a class of NSViewController.

```
ViewController : NSViewController
```

Comment: Look in your .h file and let me know if it says "`@interface ViewController : NSViewController`" like it should.  B.T.W., you should *NEVER* be so generic in your subclassed view controller names…   How about using something like "`HillsonsViewController`"?

Comment: .h files says @interface ViewController : NSViewController

Comment: Another thing, the "`NSApplication`" object is usually hiding in your "`MainMenu.xib`" file (that is, if you're using XIB files). Do you have a "`start:`" action declared anywhere in your .m or .h files? Is this the only failing connection or are there others (since you used the plural of the word *connections*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed the file's owner to my ViewController and added outlets, and the compiler seems to be happy with what I've done.

Sure, the compiler won't care -- this is a run-time error. It sounds like you're working in your MainMenu.xib file. That file is loaded by the application object. Even though you changed the type of File's Owner in the .xib, the object that's loading the .xib is still the application.

You'll probably want to create a separate .xib file for your view controller to load. You change the type of File's Owner in *that* file to you view controller class! hook things up to File's Owner, and it should work fine since your view controller really will be the object that's loading the file.

Comment: Aye, I see now that my MainMenu.xib is loaded by the application object.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, is there a way to control which object loads which xib, or is that just not a road you want to go down?

Comment: The application expects to load the main .xib file, but you can of course control which objects loads other .xib files. View controllers typically load their view hierarchies from .xib files because that's useful, but you can use NSNib to load .xibs and make any object you like the owner.