# Cannot link functions and NSObject in PyObjC and Cocoa

Tags: python-2.7, cocoa, xcode7, pyobjc

I am following a [PyObjC tutorial](http://lethain.com/an-epic-introduction-to-pyobjc-and-cocoa/). In a Xcode project, I have a MWController.py to be linked with objects in MainMenu.xib. (I did ctrl+drag & set File's Owner to MWController.)

Here is the code;

```
# MWController.py
import objc
from Foundation import *

class MWController(NSObject):
    tableView = objc.IBOutlet()
    textField = objc.IBOutlet()
    results = []

    @objc.IBAction
    def search_(self,sender):
        search_value = self.textField.stringValue()
        NSLog(u"Search: %s" % search_value)
```

So, tableView is linked with a 'Table View' NSObject. textField is linked with a 'Text Field' NSObject. search: is linked with a 'Push Button' NSObject. From the code, if I enter anything in the text field and hit the button, it would return the message in console.

However, when build and run, even though the window and interface was built up fine but the console showed,

- Failed to connect (tableView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSScrollView): missing setter or instance variable
- Failed to connect (textField) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
- Could not connect action, target class NSApplication does not respond to -search:

I checked 'connections inspector' and they all linked up fine. I did not change any function/method name. I redid the link again, too. None of them work.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very simple mistake. The reason it doesn't link has nothing to do with PyObjC at all.

As explained in the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793440/could-not-connect-the-action-to-target-of-class-nsapplication), MainMenu.xib is always loaded by the application object even if the class in File's Owner is changed.

Instead I could add a new NSObject and change its class to MWController to link it with MWController.py.